# How to identify softwares, tools, components and packages used in the website by using all codebase?

Tags: file, licensing, fortify, scanning

I am trying to develop the Software audit tool.

Is it possible to get detect softwares tools and packages used in the web application by scanning all the files of that application.

Currently I am to find out all the license related information from scanning all the files but I am not detect which all third party components used in the application

Answer (score 1):

Fortify is not the right tool to determine which OSS (Open Source Software) you have in your code. There are other commercial tools such as Blackducksoftware by Synopsis or SourceClear (I am not recommending any particular one here, those are examples). Some of those tools look for the dependencies, and some are scanning for vulnerabilities in all your OSS.

The only way to hack your way through and turn Fortify to scan for OSS could be to create custom rules to scan the comments in the code, and look for Copyright strings. This might be overkill, but I have seen such Fortify custom rules in the past.

There are also commercial tools to scan OSS directly in the binary files that you compile.

I hope this helps.